# Multiple values of a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to multiply the every column values in `df`

like `col_1 = 0.0006751475 * 0.0014568972 * 0.0012081586 * 0.0008528179 * 0.0015990335 * 0.0008528179` and same for other columns

sample `df`

```
  col_1             col_2              col_3 
0.0006751475      0.0013460512       0.0006971176                          
0.0014568972      0.0001624545       0.0003637135                          
0.0012081586      0.0009051034       0.0006364987                          
0.0008528179      0.0008122723       0.0003334041
0.0015990335      0.0003249089       0.0006364987
0.0008528179      0.0008122723       0.0003334041
```

Comment: In the end there should be a single value for each column, right?

Comment: Right sir,single value for each column

Comment: `sapply(df, prod)` in base R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse` you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate_all(funs(cumprod(.)))

         col_1        col_2        col_3
1 6.751475e-04 1.346051e-03 6.971176e-04
2 9.836205e-07 2.186721e-07 2.535511e-07
3 1.188370e-09 1.979208e-10 1.613849e-10
4 1.013463e-12 1.607656e-13 5.380640e-14
5 1.620561e-15 5.223418e-17 3.424770e-17
6 1.382043e-18 4.242838e-20 1.141832e-20
```

`cumprod()` is performing the cumulative multiplication.

Or if you want just the last row:

```
df %>%
 summarise_all(funs(last(cumprod(.))))

        col_1        col_2        col_3
1 1.382043e-18 4.242838e-20 1.141832e-20
```

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
df %>%
  summarise_all(prod)
```

Comment: Returns a single value. Assuming that's what OP needs!

Answer (score 2):

With base R

```
apply(df, 2, prod)
```

---

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  summarise_all(prod)
```

Comment: Use `vapply(df, prod, FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))` instead. A lot safer and probably faster.

Comment: @markus Thanks for the suggestion! If you're ok with it I'll add the difference in microseconds using `microbenchmark`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution using the `apply()` function in the base package.

```
# generating a sample df
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(20),nrow=4))

# using apply function to calculate the product of each column
# returns a vector
# prod = product of numbers
# margin = 2 applies it on each column
prodcol <- apply(df,FUN=prod,MARGIN=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use cumprod:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6))
```

This creates this dataframe:

```
  a b
  1 4
  2 5
  3 6

cumprod(df)
```

This'll output:

```
  a   b
  1   4
  2  20
  6 120
```

Further, you could take the last line to get the final result:

```
cumprod(df)[nrow(df), ]
```

And you just get

```
  a   b
  6 120
```

Comment: In my view, that's the best solution. I'd make it even a bit simpler with `tail( cumprod( df), 1 )`